# How to Set Taxonomy Object Description?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, post-type, oop

I noticed when dealing with Post Type Objects (Using [`get_post_type_object();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object)) and Taxonomy Objects (Using [`get_taxonomy();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy)) there's a property called "description".

How do you set this description property for Taxonomy Objects?

I don't see an option for it in [`register_taxonomy();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), but I do see an option for it in [`register_post_type();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Comment: Try setting description parameter for taxonomy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see an option for it in `register_taxonomy()`

It's not in Codex, but is fully supported:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    register_taxonomy(
      'foo',
      'post',       
      array(
        'description' => 'Hi there!'
      )
    );

    $foo = get_taxonomy( 'foo' );
    echo $foo->description; // output "Hi there!"

});
```